# Update deleted object or object that pass away

Tags: usability, user-expectation

I work on home project that has server-side API and client UI. Regardless of the techincal side, my question is about user reaction of the following situations (and how to handlie it):

- What if user change object that is already deleted?
- And if UI tracks objects state and remove or modify objects automatically from UI. Won't it be like "I saw there an object, where is it right now?"

For example, we have online photo gallery, that could be modified by group of people. How to handle situation when someone has deleted a photo just before user submit changes to that photo? Or if it deletes automatically from UI. Will user be puzzled looking for a photo that was here few seconds ago?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Communicate with your users.

You can work with a sync status (Last updated; just now) to tell users that you can have different versions of your content.

There are also a few other ways I've thought of. See the image below.

In the example below you have a notification (left image) that there have been made changes to the content. Users can click to update. When another user deletes one of your pictures, do not delete it right away for all the other users. Create a state where it is greyed out and tell users it has been deleted (right image).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nick is partially right (IMHO) but surely the issue is to prevent deletion if someone is editing an item?

Again, as Nick said, communication is key or disable & notify why a user can't delete an item at that time.

[image: Locked image]